# google chrome suddenly started to misbehave / crash

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

Everything was working fine with chrome until today it started to misbehave after use of 10-15 min.

> i've reinstalled chrome once but that didn't helped out !!
>   [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removed Adobe Flash and it started working as usual